# like query count does not match

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto, trino

If the total number of records is x and the count of "like" query is y then the count of "not like" query should be x - y

I am getting "x" as the count of "not like" query as shown below:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(b.word)) 
FROM "hunspell"."oscar2_sorted" AS b
```

> Total Count: 9597651

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct(b.word))
FROM "hunspell"."oscar2_sorted" as b 
INNER JOIN invalidswar AS a 
ON b.word LIKE (CONCAT('%', a.word,'%'))
```

> Like count: 73116

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct(b.word)) 
FROM "hunspell"."oscar2_sorted" AS b 
INNER JOIN invalidswar AS a
ON b.word NOT LIKE (CONCAT('%', a.word,'%'))
```

> Not Like count: 9597651
>
> Expected: 9524535

I am not sure what am I missing.

---

Update:

Left join count is close to expected, but still does not look correct.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(b.word))
FROM "hunspell"."oscar2_sorted" AS b 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT(b.word) AS dword 
           FROM "hunspell"."oscar2_sorted" AS b 
           INNER JOIN invalidswar AS a 
           ON b.word LIKE (CONCAT('%', a.word,'%'))) AS d 
ON d.dword = b.word 
WHERE d.dword IS NULL
```

> left join count: 9536539

---

update 2:

a difference of 12004 is traced back to the difference of how **like** and **regexp_like** is executed.

```
SELECT count(distinct(b.word)) 
          FROM "hunspell"."oscar2_sorted" as b
         INNER JOIN invalidswar AS a 
            ON regexp_like(b.word, a.word)
```

> regex like count: 61112

Comment: Try excluding records with Null value as those are not counted in like and not like both.

Comment: Verified manually that the Like Count (73116) is correct. Can someone suggest a query to exclude those records and get a count of 9524535 ?

Comment: To respond to the question of 'what am I missing', prior to the edits; if you have the word `'a'` and compare it to the list `'a', 'b', 'c'` with you inner join, then `'a'` is LIKE one of the words, but it is also NOT LIKE two of the words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(word)
  FROM (SELECT word 
          FROM "hunspell"."oscar2_sorted"
        EXCEPT DISTINCT
       (SELECT b.word
          FROM "hunspell"."oscar2_sorted" as b
         INNER JOIN invalidswar AS a 
            ON regexp_like(b.word, a.word)))
```

See: [EXCEPT clause](https://trino.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#except-clause) and [regexp_like](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/regexp.html#regexp_like)

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH
  invalid_check AS
(
  SELECT
    o.word,
    CASE WHEN
      EXISTS (
        SELECT *
          FROM invalidswar AS i
         WHERE o.word LIKE CONCAT('%', i.word,'%')
      )
    THEN
      1
    ELSE
      0
    END
      AS is_invalid
  FROM
    "hunspell"."oscar2_sorted"   AS o
  GROUP BY
    o.word
)
SELECT
  COUNT(*)            AS all_words,
  SUM(is_invalid)     AS invalid_words,
  SUM(1-is_invalid)   AS valid_words
FROM
  valid_check
```

Assuming the above matches your expectations, just counting valid words could then be...

```
SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT o.word)
FROM
  "hunspell"."oscar2_sorted"   AS o
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
      FROM invalidswar AS i
     WHERE o.word LIKE CONCAT('%', i.word,'%')
  )
```